# What happens if proguard.cfg is present for imported projects but not for main project?

Tags: android, proguard

I'm currently doing a code review of a mobile app. I have the code which has an imported sub-projects which has the proguard.cfg file for obfuscation of the sub-project. However, the main app doesn't contain proguard.cfg in its root folder. Would that affect the security of the app in anyway?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically, the main application is obfuscated together with all of its libraries, at the end of the main build process. For that purpose, ProGuard should be enabled in this main build processs. With Ant and Eclipse, you can enable it in `project.properties`. With Gradle, you can enable it in `build.gradle`. In recent versions of the Android SDK, any configuration goes in `proguard-project.txt`.